# How to remove an activity from showing in the Launcher programmatically?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher

So I have one app that displays multiple activities in the Launcher using

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

I want to know how to programmatically toggle this on/off, I will be needing to do so based on some data I will be receiving. Is this possible? If so, how can it be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `setComponentEnabledSetting()` on `PackageManager` to enable and disable the activity. Well-written home screen implementations will remove the launcher icon when you disable the activity with the `LAUNCHER` category.

However, bear in mind that some home screen implementations will cache the information that they obtain from `PackageManager` and therefore may continue to show the icon, until they refresh their contents. There is nothing much that you can do about this.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Thanks a lot. Perfect answer!